# SQL: Take 1 value per grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very simplified table / view like below to illustrate the issue:
[image: Table]

The `stock` column represents the current stock quantity of the style at the retailer. The reason the `stock` column is included is to avoid joins for reporting. (the table is created for reporting only)

I want to query the table to get what is currently in stock, grouped by stylenumber (across retailers). Like:

```
select stylenumber,sum(sold) as sold,Max(stock) as stockcount
from MGTest
```

I Expect to get Stylenumber, Total Sold, Most Recent Stock Total:

- A, 6, 15
- B, 1, 6

But using ...Max(Stock) I get 10, and with (Sum) I get 25....
I have tried with over(partition.....) also without any luck...

How do I solve this?

Comment: You will have to first group by StyleNumber AND Date. Then you will have to use STUFF and FOR XML to get the delimited values. The output here is questionable at best since delimited data is often more painful than it needs to be.

Comment: how do you get `A;6;15`?  I guess the 6 comes from sum of Sold column for your Stylenumber (1+3+2) , but 15?  how do you get that?

Comment: 15 comes from 10 (from retailer 123) + 5 ( from retailer 456)

Comment: @SeanLange: the output should not be delimitered... just wanted to show my expected result ;)  output is normal columns

Comment: But there isn't a RetailerID in your results.  How do you know you want Stlyenumber A for only RetailerID 123 (and not RetailerID 456)?

Comment: Can you show us what you really expect then as results instead of what you have? You have simplified it so much it is not representative of what you actually want as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is a bit tricky since you want a cumulative total of the `Sold` column, but only the total of the `Stock` column for the most recent date. I didn't actually try running this, but something like the query below should work. However, because of the shape of your schema this isn't the most performant query in the world since it is scanning your table multiple times to join all of the data together:

```
SELECT      MDate.Stylenumber, MDate.TotalSold, MStock.TotalStock
FROM        (SELECT M.Stylenumber, MAX(M.Date) MostRecentDate, SUM(M.Sold) TotalSold
            FROM    [MGTest] M
            GROUP BY    M.Stylenumber) MDate
INNER JOIN  (SELECT M.Stylenumber, M.Date, SUM(M.Stock) TotalStock
            FROM    [MGTest] M
            GROUP BY    M.Stylenumber, M.Date) MStock ON MDate.Stylenumber = MStock.Stylenumber AND MDate.MostRecentDate = MStock.Date
```

Comment: your description of the problem is more clear than I could formulate it (cumulative total vs total of recent)... I see the point in the suggested solution, but you are right on the scanning of the tabel.

Comment: @MortenV.Gade glad to hear this is what you were trying to convey. If this response answers your question then please mark it as the answer to close out your question.

Answer (score 2):

I would answer this using window functions:

```
SELECT Stylenumber, Date, TotalStock
FROM (SELECT M.Stylenumber, M.Date, SUM(M.Stock) as TotalStock,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY M.Stylenumber ORDER BY M.Date DESC) as seqnum
      FROM MGTest M
      GROUP BY M.Stylenumber, M.Date
     ) m
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT B.Stylenumber,SUM(B.Sold),SUM(B.Stock) FROM
(SELECT Stylenumber AS 'Stylenumber',SUM(Sold) AS 'Sold',MAX(Stock) AS 'Stock'
FROM MGTest A
GROUP BY RetailerId,Stylenumber) B
GROUP BY B.Stylenumber
```

if you don't want to use joins

Comment: I don't think you're query would calculate the the stock correctly since it is only looking at the max stock value, instead of the stock value from the latest date.

Comment: @sam2929 OP never mentioned he needs stock based of dates.. did he?

Comment: Not explicitly, but from OPs response in the comments and the desired results that were provided in the question it looks like that is what is wanted. The OP also just confirmed this in a comment on my answer.

Comment: @sam2929, just to say in my favor... he responded to your answer 7 min's after my answer.. :p

Answer (score 0):

My solution, like that of Gordon Linoff, will use the window functions. But in my case, everything will turn around the RANK window function.

```
SELECT stylenumber, sold, SUM(stock) totalstock
FROM (
  SELECT
    stylenumber,
    SUM(sold) OVER(PARTITION BY stylenumber) sold,
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY stylenumber ORDER BY [Date] DESC) r,
    stock
  FROM MGTest
) T
WHERE r = 1
GROUP BY stylenumber, sold
```